# SQL 'Invalid Column' error and conditionals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following code:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'BusinessDays' AND TABLE_NAME = 'Populations')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE Populations 
    ADD EndDay int NOT NULL DEFAULT (5)

    UPDATE Populations 
    SET EndDay = BusinessDays - 1

    ALTER TABLE Populations 
    DROP COLUMN BusinessDays
END
```

The first time I run the code it works fine, but if I run it again, I get:

> Invalid column name 'BusinessDays'.

I need to query to be able to run multiple times without error. The condition should (and does) prevent the code for executing, but why do I get this error? What is the proper way to right this code? Thanks.

Comment: The error occurs on the UPDATE line if that is not clear.

Comment: Is there another table `Populations` in a different database/schema? Try adding a condition for  `TABLE_SCHEMA`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get this error because SQL Server will try and parse the whole batch, including inside the conditional statement, and will fail at the missing column reference.

The easiest way of fixing it will be to put the offending reference in a child scope that is only compiled and executed if that `IF` statement evaluates to true.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT *
           FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
           WHERE  COLUMN_NAME = 'BusinessDays'
                  AND TABLE_NAME = 'Populations')
  BEGIN
      EXEC('ALTER TABLE Populations
              ADD EndDay INT NOT NULL DEFAULT (5)

            UPDATE Populations
            SET    EndDay = BusinessDays - 1

            ALTER TABLE Populations
              DROP COLUMN BusinessDays')
  END
```

Comment: I suspected that was what it was doing, but wasn't sure how to remedy it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are `DROP`ping the entire column from the table definition, meaning it will no longer exist when run subsequent times.

You may want to consider setting the field value to NULL instead, along with using a `WHERE` clause to identify which records you wish to update.